# How to pair mac to test flutter app using android studio in windows

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am developing an flutter app. i want to debug in both android and ios at the same time.To run in ios i can use mac but how to pair it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below command :

`flutter run -d all` will hot-reload all devices when started in terminal and pressing "s"

But this option is not available in Android studio, here is an open [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/956) for the same.

You can switch platform by using the `Toggle Platform` button of Flutter Inspector.

[image]

Comment: So there is no need of two devices for flutter, we can toggle the platform in the same device.Am i correct

Comment: yes, as of now. Already I've mentioned one issue link for the same.